# If spacebar opens dropdowns across all browsers, why is my onchange triggered menu considered inaccessible

Tags: accessibility, accessible

Background: for Windows users on Chrome and IE, dropdowns that reload or change the page are no good for accessibility. As soon as a user presses the down arrow button, the page reloads. This means that the user can only access the very first menu option. Here is an example: http://html.cita.illinois.edu/script/onchange/onchange-example.php

This is covered in the WCAG rule: 
“Changing the setting of any user interface component does not automatically cause a change of context unless the user has been advised of the behavior before using the component. (Level A)”

EXCEPT the user can very easily open up the dropdown and explore all the options without triggering an onchange event. The user does this with a space bar press. This is a very commonly known keyboard trick that I've seen all tested users to already be aware of or be able to figure out quickly.

In my system, we are using a dropdown for pagination in long directories. 
EG: "you are on page [1^] of 16" (with the [1^] being a browser default dropdown menu). The designers will not allow any kind of visual [go] button. This happens across thousands of pages, javascript fixes I've seen need to account for every dropdown, and this is impossible on our case.

Using space bar, the user can see all the options and make a selection from anywhere on the list using only the keyboard. So why are dropdown page menus that automatically reload onchange still considered inaccessible? And would they be considered accessible if we included screen-reader only text which said "press space bar to open this menu, making a selection will load your next page"

Answer (score 0):

Well except that in Firefox, the keyboard command is actually F4, you are correct - this is not a WCAG 2 violation but rather a best practice

Here is a page where you can test this: http://dylanb.github.io/onchange_select.html